# byref argument type mismatch on microsoft word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have tried everything related to this ByRef error, other programmers mentioned that I have to set the value type of each variable I create, other said to remove the type of those variables.

I truly need some help since it is my first day with VB.

The Main Idea Of the Code Below is to make a small form that after clicking, the line on the word document will scroll down or up smoothly, and of course he has the capability of increase/decrease the speed of this movement.

Here is the Main Functions:

```
Function GoDown(ByRef Speed As Integer, ByRef CounterUp As Integer, ByRef CounterDown As Integer)

    CounterUp = 0
    CounterDown = 1
    Dim NumberOfPages As Integer
    Set NumberOfPages = ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
    Dim NumberOfLines As Range
    Set NumberOfLines = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyLines)
    Dim Multiplicate As Integer
    Set Multiplicate = NumberOfPages * NumberOfLines
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Set Counter = 0
        While (Counter < Multiplicate):
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Call Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:'&Speed&'"))
            Call ActiveWindow.Close
    Call Application.Quit

End Function

Function GoUp(ByRef Speed As Integer, ByRef CounterUp As Integer, ByRef CounterDown As Integer)

    Dim NumberOfLines As Range
    Set NumberOfLines = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyLines)
    Set CounterUp = 1
    Set CounterDown = 0
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Set Counter = 0
        While (Counter < NumberOfLines):
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll up:=1
            Counter = Counter + 1
          Call Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:'&Speed&'"))

End Function

Function GoFaster(ByRef Speed As Integer, ByRef CounterUp As Integer, ByRef CounterDown As Integer)

    Speed = Speed - 1
    If (CounterUp > 0 & CounterDown = 0) Then
    Call Application.Run("btnUp_Click")
    Else: Call Application.Run("btnDown_Click")

End Function

Function GoSlower(ByRef Speed As Integer, ByRef CounterUp As Integer, ByRef CounterDown As Integer)

    Speed = Speed + 1
    If (CounterDown > 0 & CounterUp = 0) Then Call Application.Run("btnDown_Click")
    Else: If (CounterDown = 0 & CounterUp > 0) Then Call Application.Run("btnUp_Click")

End Function
```

I have tried Instead of Function to put Sub, nothing happened. I also have tried the "cint" and did not succeeded.

Here is the implementation on click events:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Speed As Integer
        Set Speed = 3
    Dim CounterUp As Integer
        Set CounterUp = 0
    Dim CounterDown As Integer
        Set CounterDown = 0

Public Sub btnDown_Click_Click()

    Call GoDown(Speed as Integer, CounterUp as Integer, CounterDown)

End Sub

Public Sub btnLeft_Click_Click()

    Call GoSlower(Speed, CounterUp, CounterDown)

End Sub

Public Sub btnRight_Click_Click()

    Call GoFaster(Speed, CounterUp, CounterDown)

End Sub

Public Sub btnUp_Click_Click()

    Call GoUp(Speed, CounterUp, CounterDown)

End Sub

End Sub
```

as You see that I have tried two methods have been mentioned in MSDN and here, but none has solved my "ByRef argument type mismatch".

Comment: Functions are supposed to return something. So are functions actually needed here? And if Subs then you call like GoDown Speed, CounterUp, CounterDown for example. Though whether ByRef is needed depends on if you are working with a changed value in a wider scope. The Call keyword is obsolete so not needed here.

Comment: Your code is riddled with problems. Besides what Ryszard and QHarr cite you can only use Set with objects - you don't use it with "simple" data types. You should start with something a bit simpler, I think, before you try such complex VBA code.

Comment: See the site guidelines for asking questions on Stack Overflow in the [help] as well as [mcve]. Your code, as it stands, cannot run and doesn't produce the error message you cite. It fails already on the second line. I'm voting to close this as off-topic:" Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: Where is `Wend` for each `While`?

Comment: @CindyMeister it does explain everything you need , and yes it does crash from the second "because i have mentioned the two way of adding the parameters as you see in callDown is different than the others ". 
And About the desired Result i think i have mentioned but maybe you do not read at all : "The Main Idea Of the Code Below is to make a small form that after clicking, the line on the word document will scroll down or up smoothly, and of course he has the capability of increase/decrease the speed of this movement".
Is this the way you help somebody by down voting his question!!!!?

Comment: Fix the first error before you ask about another. Post *exactly* the code needed to repro the question you ask about. Don't waste our time with somethint that doesn't repro. It's not as if you're paying us for helping you. Three people have tried to help you and pointed out problems - you haven't replied to any of them, nor made an effort to fix enough that we can test the error you complain about.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have Solved It .

Answer (score 0):

You can call a sub like this:

```
GoDown Speed, CounterUp, CounterDown
```

or use a function:

```
x = GoDown(Speed, CounterUp, CounterDown)
```

In attached example there are subs nested in main sub. It can't work like this, any procedure triggered by clicking will need to be separated.

Instead of Integer, always use Long or you will be encountering problems with data exceeding limitation of Integer (maximum value of 32767 and minimum of -32768).

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for who tried to help me to solve my problem , and for the unpaid philosopher .
Any way . 
Any time you need to use a variable for multiple events or multiple functions . 
you have to  :

```
`Public ThisVariable As String`
```

in the load event of the form like this :

```
FormName_Initialize()
{
ThisVariable = "The Starting value you want :)"
}
```

Thank you